# Save meta box data from selected dropdown list in bbpress reply form

Tags: plugin-development, customization, metabox, dropdown, bbpress

I hope to customize bbpress reply form area with dropdown selection list.
I could not find any previous post reporting similar case in bbpress. 
Referring to post "Save meta box data from selected dropdown list" with link 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17755973/save-meta-box-data-from-selected-dropdown-list
I prepared similar code for the bbpress reply post condition, but failed to achieve the goal.

```
 add_action( 'bbp_theme_before_reply_form_content', 'so_custom_meta_box' );
//add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'so_custom_meta_box' );

function so_custom_meta_box($post){
    add_meta_box('so_meta_box', 'Custom Box', 'custom_element_grid_class_meta_box', $post->post_type, 'normal' , 'high');
}

add_action('bbp_theme_before_reply_content', 'so_save_metabox');

function so_save_metabox(){ 
    global $post;
    if(isset($_POST["custom_element_grid_class"])){
         //UPDATE: 
        $meta_element_class = $_POST['custom_element_grid_class'];
        //END OF UPDATE

        update_post_meta($reply_id, 'custom_element_grid_class_meta_box', $meta_element_class);
        //print_r($_POST);
    }
}
function custom_element_grid_class_meta_box($post){
    $reply_id = bbp_get_reply_id();
    $meta_element_class = get_post_meta($reply_id, 'custom_element_grid_class_meta_box', true); //true ensures you get just one value instead of an array
    ?>   
    <label>Choose the size of the element :  </label>

    <select name="custom_element_grid_class" id="custom_element_grid_class">
      <option value="normal" <?php selected( $meta_element_class, 'normal' ); ?>>normal</option>
      <option value="square" <?php selected( $meta_element_class, 'square' ); ?>>square</option>
      <option value="wide" <?php selected( $meta_element_class, 'wide' ); ?>>wide</option>
      <option value="tall" <?php selected( $meta_element_class, 'tall' ); ?>>tall</option>
    </select>
    <?php
}
```

Could anybody can provide kind help to solve the problem? Thanks!

Comment: This code can't work. Metaboxes are supported by WordPress on admin side only, they can't be rendered in any random place on the frontend. Adding fields to bbPress frontend forms is possible, but not like this.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, Milan Petrovic! The code will be part of plugin in my bbpress forum. So could you please kindly describe the mistakes in the codes?

Answer (score 0):

I add a show contents part referring to a workable previous post with link https://bbpress.org/forums/topic/add-custom-text-fields-to-reply-form/. 
The below code can provide options for the user to selection. But the selection result could not be shown. I am not sure whether the selection result was added into metabox properly because I can not use the debug function. And another problem is that the “Field 1 ” was inserted into all previous reply posts.
Could anybody further provide help to solve this problem？

```
add_action( 'bbp_theme_before_reply_form_content', 'so_additional_content' );
function so_additional_content($post){
    $reply_id = bbp_get_reply_id();
    $meta_element_class = get_post_meta($reply_id, 'custom_element_grid_class', true);
    //$meta_element_class = get_post_meta($reply_id, 'custom_element_grid_class_meta_box', true); //true ensures you get just one value instead of an array
    ?>   
    echo '<label>Choose the size of the element :  </label>

    <select name="custom_element_grid_class" id="custom_element_grid_class">
      <option value="normal" <?php selected( $meta_element_class, 'normal' ); ?>>normal</option>
      <option value="square" <?php selected( $meta_element_class, 'square' ); ?>>square</option>
      <option value="wide" <?php selected( $meta_element_class, 'wide' ); ?>>wide</option>
      <option value="tall" <?php selected( $meta_element_class, 'tall' ); ?>>tall</option>
    </select>'
    <?php
}



add_action('bbp_new_reply_post_extras', 'so_save_metabox');

function so_save_metabox(){ 
    global $post;
    if(isset($_POST["custom_element_grid_class"])) {
         //check the capability: if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post->ID ))  return $post->ID;
        $meta_element_class = $_POST['custom_element_grid_class'];
        //END OF UPDATE

          update_post_meta($reply_id, 'custom_element_grid_class', $meta_element_class);
        //update_post_meta($reply_id, 'custom_element_grid_class_meta_box', $meta_element_class);
        //print_r($_POST);

    }
}


add_action('bbp_theme_before_reply_content', 'so_show_metabox');

function so_show_metabox() {
    $meta_element_class = get_post_meta($reply_id, 'custom_element_grid_class', true);
  //$meta_element_class = get_post_meta($reply_id, 'custom_element_grid_class_meta_box', true);
  // the problem is "Field 1" appear in every reply post
  echo "Field 1: ".$meta_element_class."End of testing "."<br>";  
}
```